# Ionic 2 How to Process an Array build up from a databasequery in a service

Tags: arrays, sqlite, ionic2

I'm trying to loop trough an array provided via a different method in the same service. However when I try it for some reason users is undefined.

**The method where the error occurs in:**

```
 public toString() {
        let users: any;
        users = this.getAllUsers();
        for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
            var userData = users[i];
            console.log(" User: " + userData.iduser + " " + userData.firstname + " " + userData.lastname);
            let meldingen: any;
            meldingen = this.getMeldingenFromUser(userData.iduser);
            for (var ii = 0; i < meldingen.length; i++) {
                var meldingData = meldingen[ii];
                console.log("- Melding: " + meldingData.idmelding + " " + meldingData.description);
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

**other used methods:**

getAllUsers():

```
public getAllUsers() {
        this.database.executeSql('SELECT * FROM user', []).then((resultSet) => {
            if (resultSet.rows.length > 0) {
                this.users = [];
                for (let i = 0; i < resultSet.rows.length; i++) {
                    this.users.push({
                        "iduser": resultSet.rows.item(i).iduser,
                        "firstname": resultSet.rows.item(i).firstname,
                        "lastname": resultSet.rows.item(i).lastname,
                    });
                }
                console.log('returning all users: ');
                console.log(JSON.stringify(this.users));
                return this.users;
            }
        })
    }
```

getMeldingenFromUser():

```
public getMeldingenFromUser(iduser) {
        this.database.executeSql('SELECT * FROM melding, user WHERE melding.user_iduser = user.iduser AND user.iduser = ' + iduser + ';', []).then((resultSet) => {
            if (resultSet.rows.length > 0) {
                this.users = [];
                for (let i = 0; i < resultSet.rows.length; i++) {
                    this.users.push({
                        "idmelding": resultSet.rows.item(i).idmelding,
                        "meldingType": resultSet.rows.item(i).meldingType,
                        "meldingTitel": resultSet.rows.item(i).meldingTitle,
                        "meldingOmschrijving": resultSet.rows.item(i).meldingOmschrijving,
                        "guidRuimte": resultSet.rows.item(i).ruimte,
                        "iduser": resultSet.rows.item(i).user_idUser,
                    });
                }
                console.log('Returning all kasteelonderdelen from user: ' + iduser);
                console.log(JSON.stringify(this.users));
            }
        })
        return this.users;
    }
```

**output log:**

```
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js: Line 12 : EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(12)] "EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js (12)
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js: Line 12 : ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(12)] "ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js (12)
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js: Line 12 : Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
                                                                                               at s (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:8568)
                                                                                               at file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:8318
                                                                                               at t.invoke (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:13422)
                                                                                               at Object.inner.inner.fork.onInvoke (file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js:3:23082)
                                                                                               at t.invoke (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:13373)
                                                                                               at e.run (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:10809)
                                                                                               at file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:8911
                                                                                               at t.invokeTask (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:14051)
                                                                                               at Object.inner.inner.fork.onInvokeTask (file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js:3:22982)
                                                                                               at t.invokeTask (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:13987)
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(12)] "Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
                                                                                  at s (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:8568)
                                                                                  at file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:8318
                                                                                  at t.invoke (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:13422)
                                                                                  at Object.inner.inner.fork.onInvoke (file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js:3:23082)
                                                                                  at t.invoke (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:13373)
                                                                                  at e.run (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:10809)
                                                                                  at file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:8911
                                                                                  at t.invokeTask (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:14051)
                                                                                  at Object.inner.inner.fork.onInvokeTask (file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js:3:22982)
                                                                                  at t.invokeTask (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:13987)", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js (12)
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js: Line 3 : Unhandled Promise rejection:
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(3)] "Unhandled Promise rejection:", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js (3)
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js: Line 3 : Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(3)] "Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js (3)
01-02 08:35:51.890 1175-1175/? I/Keyboard.Facilitator: onFinishInput()
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js: Line 5 : returning all users: 
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(5)] "returning all users: ", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js (5)
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js: Line 5 : [{"iduser":1,"firstname":"Peter","lastname":"Pan"},{"iduser":2,"firstname":"Jan","lastname":"Jaap"},{"iduser":3,"firstname":"Karel","lastname":"Kast"},{"iduser":4,"firstname":"Roos","lastname":"Rozijn"}]
01-02 08:35:51.985 24904-24904/com.ionicframework.cwistlev1105374 I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(5)] "[{"iduser":1,"firstname":"Peter","lastname":"Pan"},{"iduser":2,"firstname":"Jan","lastname":"Jaap"},{"iduser":3,"firstname":"Karel","lastname":"Kast"},{"iduser":4,"firstname":"Roos","lastname":"Rozijn"}
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Poerkie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These functions are returning `Promise` (should be returning `Promise` ) . You can only access values inside `then` callback. Learn more about `Promise` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). You need to chain all the promises with `then` .

for example

```
public getMeldingenFromUser(iduser) {
        return this.database.executeSql('SELECT * FROM melding, user WHERE melding.user_iduser = user.iduser AND user.iduser = ' + iduser + ';', []).then((resultSet) => {
            if (resultSet.rows.length > 0) {
                this.users = [];
                for (let i = 0; i < resultSet.rows.length; i++) {
                    this.users.push({
                        "idmelding": resultSet.rows.item(i).idmelding,
                        "meldingType": resultSet.rows.item(i).meldingType,
                        "meldingTitel": resultSet.rows.item(i).meldingTitle,
                        "meldingOmschrijving": resultSet.rows.item(i).meldingOmschrijving,
                        "guidRuimte": resultSet.rows.item(i).ruimte,
                        "iduser": resultSet.rows.item(i).user_idUser,
                    });
                }
                console.log('Returning all kasteelonderdelen from user: ' + iduser);
                console.log(JSON.stringify(this.users));
                return this.users;
            }
        })
    }
```

Now you can access them as,

```
this.getMeldingenFromUser(iduser).then((users)=>{
  console.log(users); // do what you want with users
})
```

Comment: it gives the following error: Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void' I asume I need to specify in the method that it needs to return an array? if so which type should I specify?

Comment: you have to ``return`` the ``Promise`` as I mentioned in the example.